# Formatting time in JSON to display in ag-grid

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid with angular 5.
My goal is to have a grid with some columns where one of the columns is a "Time" column and shows the time in this format "*hh:mm*".

All the data I am displaying in the grid comes from a JSON object. Right now the time I am displaying looks like this "*2018-04-28T08:16:07.632Z*".

I have looked a bit on Angular Pipes but I can't figure how to use it for a JSON object where I need one column formatted, but it needs to be "bound" to the correct cells in the other columns. I think all the formatting have to be done in the typescript code.

Have any of you done something similar or have an idea have to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found an identical question on this and it was very simple so I will explain what I did:

In the coulmDefs I added *valueFormatter: HomePage.timeFormatter*

```
columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Time', field: 'time', valueFormatter: HomePage.timeFormatter}]
```

Then I added this function to the same file:

```
// I take the substring of this '2018-04-28T08:16:07.632Z' and I get '08:16'
static timeFormatter(params) {return params.value.substring(11, 16);}
```

Keep in mind that this only works when you know the DateTime comes in the same format every time.

Answer (score 1):

In Ag-Grid you have the grid-options that you define at some point:

```
this.gridOptions = {
  // ...
  columnDefs: [    'DATE': {
     headerName: 'Datum',
     field: 'myJson.date',
     cellRenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams) => params.value ? 
        `<div class="my-awesome-date-style">${this._customDatePipe.transform(params.value)}</div>` : ''
  }],
  // ...
}
```

To use a pipe (be it your own CustomDatePipe or Angular's native DatePipe) inside a typescript-file (e.g. outside of a template), you have to inject it:

```
constructor(private readonly _customDatePipe: CustomDatePipe) {}
```

and include CustomDatePipe (or CommonModule for native DatePipe) in your module's providers.

The pipe's transform() method will format the part of the JSON (in your case the date-property) you want to display as soon as AgGrid tries to render it.

PS: If you are using an AgGrid CellRenderer-Component, you can just use the pipe directly in it's template without injection (need to put in providers still though):

`<div class="my-awesome-date-style">${params.date | customDatePipe}</div>`

Comment: This could probably work, but because of your answer I stumbled upon this doc https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/ that says "If you just want to do simple formatting of the data (eg currency or date formatting) then you can use colDef.valueFormatter", so I decided to go for the valueFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Angular2+ version. If you are using moment library in your application. Then the job is really simple

**In your .ts file:**

```
    import * as moment from 'moment';

{
    headerName: 'End Date',
    field: 'endDateUTC',
    minWidth: 80,
    maxWidth: 100,
    valueFormatter: function (params) {
        return moment(params.value).format('hh:mm');
    },
},
```

And the output you will get is:

End date: 
10:55

Using moment library you can configure many date formats including locale support.

Hope this will be helpful to some one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will create a Pipe and also mommentjs within this Pipe.

Comment: From my experience Angular's Date-pipe can do most of what people use moment.js for. I would recommend trying to use the DatePipe either directly or as an injected service in a `CustomDatePipe` before integrating an additional framework.

Comment: Excelent cooment, I have present for others